# Why does the IF of an RF mixer not go down to DC?

Tags: microwave, mixer

Consider [this](http://storefront.brackemfg.com/storefrontCommerce/categorybrowse.do;jsessionid=2CF0E122E2445BC2B1187D4810C394A8?category-name=Balanced%20Mixers&path=) mixer:

“SMA Triple Balance Mixer RF/LO Freq. 6-18 GHz IF Freq. 2-8 GHz”

If my RF is 18 GHz and my LO is 17 GHz then the IF should be 1 GHz. But the product somehow has a minimum of 2 GHz. This is common for other mixers as well. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a triple-balanced mixer, as opposed to a double-balanced (or single-balanced, or unbalanced) mixer. The one you have here has three single-ended ports, each of which is coupled into the mixer core using baluns, while the mixer core performs a fully differential * differential -> differential mixing operation.

This gives it an advantage of operating effectively when the RF/LO and IF bands overlap, but as a downside it cannot operate down to DC by design. If you apply an RF of 18 GHz and an LO of 17 GHz you will be out of spec and may receive an attenuated or distorted IF. I believe that is a result of the limitations of the balun on the IF port, which cannot operate down to DC.

If you review the link you listed, you'll see that all of the double-balanced mixers *do* support DC at the IF port, but do not allow IF and RF/LO to overlap.

Answer (score 3):

> If my RF is 18 GHz and my LO is 17 GHz then the IF should be 1 GHz. But the product somehow has a minimum of 2 GHz. This is common for other mixers as well. Why is that?

If you supply a 17 GHz LO and an 18 GHz RF, then sure enough, the mixer will generate IFs of 1 GHz and 35 GHz. However, a triple balanced mixer uses a balun between the mixer diodes and the IF port, and this balun hasn't been designed to work below 2 GHz. You'll probably still get *some* signal out at 1 GHz, but rather less than from a mixer designed to work at that frequency.

There are plenty of double balanced mixers available with a direct IF connection to the diodes that go down to DC. I often use one as a phase detector for an RF PLL.